# java poi skips cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

this is how i iterate through my xls file:

```
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

        String cellValue="",cellComment=cell.getCellComment()!=null?cell.getCellComment().getString().toString().trim():"";

        switch(cell.getCellType()){
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                cellValue=(cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"").trim();
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                cellValue=(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"").trim();
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                cellValue=(cell.getStringCellValue()+"").trim();
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                switch(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()){
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        cellValue=(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"").trim();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        cellValue=(cell.getStringCellValue()+"").trim();
                        break;
                    default:
                        try{cellValue=cell.toString().trim();}
                        catch(Exception ex){cellValue="";}
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                try{cellValue=cell.toString().trim();}
                catch(Exception ex){cellValue="";}
                break;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

some cell valueas are extracted well and some are like they do not exist at all.

i've tried many ways to extract cell value:

```
sheet.getRow(1).getCell(16).toString();
row.getCell(16).toString();
row.getCell(16).getStringCellValue();
```

but i allways fail!

can somebody explain why it happens to me!
it's definately not because encoding coz some cells with non latin symbols are extracted well.

this is the link to the xls file so you can see by yourself http://best-shina.zp.ua/frontend/files/PRICE.xls
at this file col 13 are skipped like it did not exist and all next cols are shifted and they have numbers n-1.
any help appriciated!

Comment: Rows and cells are zero-based indexed, try changing to `sheet.getRow(0).getCell(15)`.

Comment: No. it returns me some cell values but doesnt return cell value for cpecific cell in column 13

Comment: I just executed it - `System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(12).toString());` prints `4.0`, which is exactly what in the file.

Comment: yeah, but didn't you notice that it actually in 13-th column?

Comment: ok. i've just truied it and its fine. but however if i iterate through it still skips 13 column

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells,+with+control+of+missing+/+blank+cells